# How can I get Model Records that do not have a relation?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is there a 'whereDoesNotHave' kind of method in Laravel to get records that have no relations?

I have a query that checks if Users has a Team, or their name is David, but just don't know how to write this query:

```
User::where(function($query){ 
     $query->where('name', 'David')->orWhere($this->teams->count() , '<' , 1);
})
  ->get();
```

I need something like this.

**UPDATE**

Forgot to mention - the relation is many-to-many, users can have multiple teams

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your **User Model**, you probably have a relation to **Team Model**

```
// in User Model
public function team()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Team', 'team_id');
}
```

This would be the default way to relate a User to a Team, logically.

If this is the case, that means you have a *team_id* field in your *users* table.
So only thing you have to do, is to look for Users with null team_id field.

And that would be;

```
$q = User::where('team_id',null)->orWhere('name','David')->get();
```

**Edit:**
If your relation is *many to many* however (Each user may belong to multiple teams), you should use [Eloquent's **has()**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) method;

```
$users = User::has('teams', '0')->orWhere('name', 'David')->get();
```

**NOTE:**
as [patricus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3583182/patricus) pointed [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34785157/4306828);

Using Eloquent method `doesntHave()` also works, and seems more proper in this case.

Comment: The second parameter to `has()` is the operator, not the number. Should be `has('teams', '<', 1)`.

Comment: @patricus I think it is not so. I found `has()` is much like `where()` in regards of parameters. If you provide 2 parameters, it is automatically checks for equality: `has('arg1', 'arg2')` = `has('arg1,'=','arg2')`. If you provide three however, second one is interpreted as operator. So you could use `has('team',5)` to get users that only in 5 teams. Still, I have added a note to my answer about `doesntHave()` because I think it would be more proper to use that instead.

Comment: @Lazysheepherd Ah, you are correct. I was looking at the code, and just didn't go deep enough. `has()` eventually calls `where()`, which is why that notation works. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `doesntHave()` method:

```
$users = User::doesntHave('teams')->orWhere('name', 'David')->get();
```

If you need to "OR" it, the second parameter lets you change that:

```
$users = User::where('name', 'David')->doesntHave('teams', 'or')->get();
```